# How to access data from Context Provider using useContext?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to access data from Context Provider using useContext 
when whole state is passed inside of value

Suppose my state is like this

```
const state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    Key: 12345,
    data: "Hi"
};
```

I have passed this state inside of context api by provider

```
        <AuthContext.Provider 
            value = {{state , dispatch}}
        >
        </AuthContext.Provider>
```

Now i am trying to access it in another component by this way but it throws error

```
const { {state.key: auth},{state.data : data} } = useContext(AuthContext)
```

Now can i use `auth` and `data` anywhere inside of jsx

As i want to access the key and data from context api

Answer (score 1):

Your other component needs to be wrapped in Context Provider.

Docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to use React's `useContext`hook you need to wrap the components with the context's provider. Read more about [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Here is an example with your case:

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

function AuthProvider(props) {
  const [state] = React.useState({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    key: 12345,
    data: "Hi",
  });

  // Any function has to be wrapped in a React.useCallback
  // to avoid re-calculation in any dependency array
  const dispatch = React.useCallback(() => {}, []); // Redux or useReducer dispatch

  // We have to wrap our values in React.useMemo to avoid any unnecessary re-renders
  const values = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      state,
      dispatch,
    }),
    [dispatch, state]
  );

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={values} {...props} />;
}

function useAuth() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      "To utilize `useAuth`, component must be wrapped in `AuthProvider`"
    );
  }
  return context;
}

function Component() {
  const {
    state: { data, key },
  } = useAuth();

  // ...
}

function App() {
  return (
    // Everything wrapped in AuthProvider will have access to its values
    <AuthProvider>
      <Component />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```